# CSS for text inside a ribbon/pennant type shape

Tags: css

Im looking to replicate something like this but as a relatively new guy to CSS, I cannot for the life of me figure out the appropriate CSS to create this shape around the text.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un68Y.png)

Really appreciate any help you can give. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `text-align` and `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);`  to start with maybe ? here a tool to help you with clip-path https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ Please add your html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. But you can split it in 2 separate shapes.

Rectangular shape ( background of the text ) and a triangle using a pseudo element.
See below

Tweak around with the border values of the `after` element to achieve exactly the shape you want.

```css
span {
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  content: '';
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
   My Text
</span>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is the one. Thank you!

Comment: @thecodenewbie glad i could help. But you should know there are tons of questions/answers about this on the web. 90% of developing is knowing how to do your research :) . Also,  Feel free to rate/accept ( green tick ) my answer :d Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There you go

Note that you can play around with the border-left value in `#snippet:after` to increase or reduce the "arrow section"

```css
 #snippet {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
    }
    #snippet:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
      border: 75px solid transparent;
      border-left: 30px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="snippet">Hello</div>
```

Comment: what is `:before` used for ?

Comment: Good point, you don't need it at all, just force of habit because of one of my current projects, will update the answer